# Datatable json error - works fine in localhost

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dtable = $('#booking_list').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "cache": false,
        "ajax": "ajaxnew.php",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "date" },
            { "data": "service_type" }
        ]
    } );

    setInterval( function () {
        dtable.ajax.reload();
    }, 60000 );
});
```

and AJAX file

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'date', 'dt' => 'date',
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array( 'db' => 'service_type',   'dt' => 'service_type' )
);
```

I am getting following error:

`Datatable warning: table id= booking_list cant reinitialize data table`

Note: The above code works fine in `localhost` but doesn't work on my server.

Comment: can you please add 

"bDestroy": true

to datatable initialization? and check

Comment: @Trupti nope still same..

Answer (score 0):

when you are going to initialized table somewhere and it was already initizalised before,this error is coming up.

so destroy it with  `tableInstancename.destroy();`

before

```
var dtable = $('#booking_list').DataTable( {
```

this line

Answer (score 0):

This means you are re-initializing (re-declaring) the `DataTable` .

Try this:

```
var dtable = $('#booking_list').DataTable( {
            destroy: true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "cache": false,
            "ajax": "ajaxnew.php",
             "columns": [
                { "data": "date" },
                { "data": "service_type" }
            ]
        } );
```